# In PHP, how do I rename an array key without moving it at the end?

Tags: php, arrays, rename

I need to write an array in a CSV file where column order must not be changed. But I want to reduce column titles to a length of max 64 chars. To make the question more general, let's take a simple example :

```
$array = array(
    'A te' => 'foo A',
    'Q test' => 'foo Q',
    'Z test' => 'foo Z',
);

var_dump($array);
```

Give :

```
array (size=3)
  'A te' => string 'foo A' (length=5)
  'Q test' => string 'foo Q' (length=5)
  'Z test' => string 'foo Z' (length=5)
```

Now, I want to rename the "Q test" key to "Q tes". If I do :

```
$swap = $array["Q test"];
unset($array["Q test"]);
$array["Q tes"] = $swap;
var_dump($array);
```

Displays :

```
array (size=3)
  'A te' => string 'foo A' (length=5)
  'Z test' => string 'foo Z' (length=5)
  'Q tes' => string 'foo Q' (length=5)
```

The column's position changed, that's not what I was looking for.

I solved my problem by using (here, reducing keys to 5 chars) :

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
$count = count($keys);
for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
{
   if (mb_strlen($keys[$i]) > 5)
   {
      $keys[$i] = mb_substr($keys[$i], 0, 5);
   }
}
$array = array_combine($keys, $values);

var_dump($array);
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=3)
  'A te' => string 'foo A' (length=5)
  'Q tes' => string 'foo Q' (length=5)
  'Z tes' => string 'foo Z' (length=5)
```

But this looks very resources-devour... I do need to execute such a code on each of my rows, and I have from 10k to 100k rows.

Is there a simpler way to rename array keys without moving them?

Comment: Have a look at array_map, used in combination with array_keys. In the end, however, it probably does the same as your own solution.

Comment: Why not just truncate the titles at output time, rather than changing the array? Your question doesn't make it clear why you need to shorten the array's keys (which might lead to overlapping keys and data loss).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which should be simpler,

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
   if($k=='Q test'){
      $new_arr['Q tes'] = $array['Q test'];
   }else{
      $new_arr[$k] = $v;
   }
}

print_r($new_arr); //set $array = $new_arr;  to overwrite all values
```

Comment: Hmm, looks good, I focused on key replacement, I didn't thought about simply create a new array.